# Prove that $\frac{z^{1/4}}{z^2+4}$ is not holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I am trying to prove that the function $f(z)= \frac{z^{1/4}}{z^2+4}$ is not holomorphic in $0$. I was thinking, is it okay to just say that if I look at it as a $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ function, it is not differentiable because its partial derivatives does not exist? I mean, is it enough to just say that the function is not differentiable because $f(x)= \frac{x^{1/4}}{x^2+4}$ is not derivable in $0$ (and the same for $y$ of course)?

Comment: The issue is $z^{1/4}$ is not defined (continuously) in a neighborhood of the origin, so it doesn't make sense to ask if it is holomorphic there.

Comment: @tommy yes, the reason given by you is correct

Comment: And how is $z^{1/4}$ defined?

Comment: @zhw. it was not specified in the exercise, but I think it was meant to be $|z|^{1/4} e^{i*Arg(z)/4}$